# Memory Leak issue in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

Getting error in component but in component there is no async call didn't get why still getting this issue

Here is my Code

```
 import { Checkbox, DatePicker, Form, Input, Select } from 'antd';
 import moment from 'moment';
 import React, { memo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const { TextArea } = Input;
const { Option } = Select;

const actorsOptions = [];

    const directorsOptions = [];

 function BasicDetails({
  basicFormFields,
  onChangeValues,
  mandatoryFields,
  metaDetails,
  type,
  }) {
 const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const [sameDescription, setSameDescription] = useState(false);
  const [longDesc, setLongDesc] = useState('');

 /**
  * if desc are same
  * @param condition
  */
 const onSameAsShortDescription = async condition => {
  let value = '';
   if (condition) {
   value = await form.getFieldValue('shortDescription');
  }
await form.setFieldsValue({ description: value });
 setLongDesc(value);
 onChangeValues(value, 'longDesc');
 setSameDescription(condition);
};

return (
 <div className="basicFormWrapper">
  <div className="form-heading">Basic Details</div>
  <Form
    form={form}
    labelCol={{ span: 5 }}
    wrapperCol={{ span: 19 }}
    style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
    layout="horizontal"
    initialValues={metaDetails}
  >
    {basicFormFields.title && (
      <Form.Item
        name="title"
        label="Title"
        rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('t') }]}
      >
        <Input
          placeholder={`${type} Name`}
          onChange={e =>
            onChangeValues(e.target.value, basicFormFields.title)
          }
        />
      </Form.Item>
    )}
    {basicFormFields.shortDesc && (
      <Form.Item
        name="shortDescription"
        label="Short Description"
        rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('sds') }]}
      >
        <Form.Item name="shortDescription">
          <TextArea
            placeholder={`Add ${type} Short Description`}
            autoSize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 6 }}
            onChange={e => {
              onChangeValues(e.target.value, basicFormFields.shortDesc);
              if (sameDescription) {
                setLongDesc(e.target.value);
                onChangeValues(e.target.value, basicFormFields.longDesc);
              }
            }}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form.Item>
    )}
    {basicFormFields.longDesc && (
      <Form.Item
        name="description"
        label="Description"
        rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('ds') }]}
      >
        <TextArea
          disabled={sameDescription}
          value={longDesc}
          placeholder={`Add ${type} Description`}
          autoSize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 6 }}
          onChange={e => {
            setLongDesc(e.target.value);
            onChangeValues(e.target.value, basicFormFields.longDesc);
          }}
        />
        <Form.Item name="sameAsShortDescription">
          <Checkbox
            checked={metaDetails.sameAsShortDescription}
            onChange={e => {
              metaDetails.sameAsShortDescription = !metaDetails.sameAsShortDescription;
              onSameAsShortDescription(e.target.checked);
            }}
          >
            Same as short description
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form.Item>
    )}

    {basicFormFields.actors && (
      <Form.Item
        name="actors"
        label="Actors"
        rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('actors') }]}
      >
        <Select
          mode="tags"
          placeholder="Actors Name"
          onChange={selection =>
            onChangeValues(selection, basicFormFields.actors)
          }
        >
          {actorsOptions}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    )}
    {basicFormFields.directors && (
      <Form.Item
        name="directors"
        label="Directors"
        rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('directors') }]}
      >
        <Select
          mode="tags"
          placeholder="Directors Name"
          onChange={selection =>
            onChangeValues(selection, basicFormFields.directors)
          }
        >
          {directorsOptions}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    )}

    <Form.Item
      name="relYr"
      label="Release Year"
      rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('relYr') }]}
    >
      {basicFormFields.year && (
        <Form.Item
          style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '55%' }}
          name="relYr"
        >
          <DatePicker
            defaultValue={
              metaDetails.releaseYear &&
              moment({ year: metaDetails.releaseYear })
            }
            picker="year"
            onChange={(_date, year) =>
              onChangeValues(year, basicFormFields.year)
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>
      )}
      {basicFormFields.isFree && (
        <Form.Item
          name="isFree"
          rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('isFree') }]}
          style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '20%' }}
          label=""
          valuePropName="checked"
        >
          <Checkbox
            checked={metaDetails.isFree}
            onChange={e => {
              metaDetails.isFree = !metaDetails.isFree;
              onChangeValues(e.target.checked, basicFormFields.isFree);
            }}
          >
            Is Free
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
      )}
      {basicFormFields.isDownloadable && (
        <Form.Item
          rules={[{ required: mandatoryFields.includes('isDownloadable') }]}
          style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '25%' }}
          name="isDownloadable"
          label=""
          valuePropName="checked"
        >
          <Checkbox
            checked={metaDetails.isDownloadable}
            onChange={e => {
              metaDetails.isDownloadable = !metaDetails.isDownloadable;
              onChangeValues(
                e.target.checked,
                basicFormFields.isDownloadable,
              );
            }}
          >
            Is Downloadable
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
      )}
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
</div>
```

);
}

export default memo(BasicDetails);

Component where called above component

```
  import {debounce} from 'lodash'
 const TvShowMetadetailForm = props => {
 const { title } = props;



const onChangeValues = (value, field) => {
  console.log('fake value', value, field);
};
return (
 <FormWrapper>
  <label className="heading">{title}</label>
  <BasicDetails
    type="Tv Show"
    metaDetails={{
      isFree: true,
      isDownloadable: true,
      sameAsShortDescription: false,
    }}
    mandatoryFields={[]}
    onChangeValues={debounce(onChangeValues, 300)}
    basicFormFields={basicForm}
  />
</FormWrapper>
 );
 };

export default MetadetailForm;
```

getting error while basicdetails component is unmount

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in FormItem (created by BasicDetails)

Didn't found any call which is pending while unmounting

Comment: Ciao, the only thing I see that could pending while unmounting `BasicDetails` is the `debounce` function.

Comment: It's not really an "error" as much as it is a warning. . .

Comment: Also, the `basicForm` value being assigned to basicFormFields, where is it defined?